# What is the meaning of the phrase 'from the soil' here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> ‘Cremuel,’ he says, ‘I note the duke’s comments. About your person.
>   About your position.’ He clears his throat. ‘For what it is worth, I
>   am myself a man of humble origins. Though not perhaps so low…’
>
> He knows Chapuys’s history. His people are petty lawyers, two
>   generations away **from the soil**.
>
> *Bring Up the Bodies by Hilary Mantel*

What is the meaning of the phrase '**from the soil**' here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Two generations away from the soil" means that two generations back, Chapuy's family were farmers.

Similar expressions:
One's grandparent's could have

- Worked the land
- Followed/chased the plow.

Answer (score 1):

Probably two generations away from being farmers, ie people who work in the soil.

There is also a possible allusion to `night soil` meaning faeces, ie referring to people who work in, or with, middens and similar.